# org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property while saving master child records

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, one-to-one

I have a master table and child table with one to one relationship. The child table id field is reference field of master table and it's a primary key too. The ID field to master table is not autogenerated and it will be set manually. While saving the object along with child reference it throws error below error "org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

I have provided the code for reference.

Note:- If I make the ID key in master table as autogenerated then it works fine. But I want to pass the ID that we receive from JSON request.

```
package com.entities;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name="MASTER")
public class Master {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ORDER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long orderId;

    @Column(name="MasterNumber", length = 17)
    private String masterNumber;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "master", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Child child;

    @Column(name="Received_Date")
    private Timestamp receivedDate;

    public long getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(long orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getMasterNumber() {
        return masterNumber;
    }

    public void setMasterNumber(String masterNumber) {
        this.masterNumber = masterNumber;
    }

    public Child getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
        this.child.setMaster(this);
    }

    public Timestamp getReceivedDate() {
        return receivedDate;
    }

    public void setReceivedDate(Timestamp receivedDate) {
        this.receivedDate = receivedDate;
    }
}

package com.entities;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ORDER_ID")
    private long orderId;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ORDER_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FK_Master_Child_REF"), nullable = false)
    private Master master;

    public long getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(long orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public Master getMaster() {
        return master;
    }

    public void setMaster(Master master) {
        this.master = master;
        this.setOrderId(master.getOrderId());
    }
}
```

Repository class

```
package com.dao;


import com.entities.Master;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface MasterRepository extends CrudRepository<Master, Long> {
}
```

Helper method to save

```
public void Save(Master master)
{
    masterRepository.save(master);


}



java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp currentTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());
Master master = new Master();
master.setOrderId(1212L);
master.setMasterNumber("M001");
master.setReceivedDate(currentTime);

Child child = new Child();
child.setMaster(master);
master.setChild(child);
Helper.Save(master);
```

I expect both master and child records to get inserted. But I am getting the below error.

> "org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign
>   id from null one-to-one property

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to do bi directional mapping ?

Comment: Not really. For me I am trying to save data to both master and child tables and child table ID will be primary as well as foreign key and that's the reason I used @MapsId. If I make primary key as autogenerated or remove the mapsId annotation then it works fine. As I told earlier I can't have primary key autogenerated. Removing mapsId will remove the foreign key functionality. Even though I can create DB with all keys and at POJO level I can remove the MapsId but I want to be sync will db as well as pojo.

Comment: Also I followed this https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Try using @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) on orderId

Comment: Like I told earlier generated value works but as per our requirement I can’t use it.